# Dynamically dimension a two-dimensional array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm modelling Petri nets using VBA in Excel, and I want to be able to vary the number of species and transitions, and the links between them. I'm hoping to do this by reading straight off the Shapes used to draw the network, rather than explicitly inputting the matrices. This means I have to dynamically dimension my array variables. I can do this for the one-dimensional arrays, but the Species-Transition links require two-dimensional arrays. Is there any way of doing this, or will I have to fall back on using the spreadsheet to store my variables in?

Comment: I think you're looking for `ReDim`. Here's the MSDN write-up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx

Comment: I made a Matrix class for use in developing a Gaussian Elimination method.  If that would be interesting to you, I can provide it as an answer.

Comment: @Dan doesn't that require me to use constants as the array sizes? I need it to check the number of place-nodes and transition-nodes at run time and set those as the sizes of the two dimensions of the array. When I try it, it generates an error and tells me I have to use a constant.

Comment: @Blackhawk That does sound interesting, but I think it's probably way more than I need for this problem. Still...tempting. Go on then. Hit me.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. Could you post your code?

Comment: @Dan Actually, Dan: when I write "Dim(r,c)"
r = Range("A1"): c = Range("B1")
Dim U(r, c) As Double
it gives me "Compile Error: Constant expression required".
When I write 
Dim U(1, 1) As Double
r = Range("A1"): c = Range("B1")
ReDim U(r, c)
It comes back with "Compile error: array already dimensioned".
Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to use the values from A1 and B1 to determine the dimensions of your array, or are you trying to store Range objects in the array?

Comment: Using those two cells (for demonstration purposes only) to determine the dimensions of the array. In actual usage I'll be calculating those values elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry, @Dan, my example is hard to read. I tried posting it using backticks as required, but that doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You can add the code to your original question by selecting the "edit" option -- the markdown is described very succinctly there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your worksheet looks like this:

[image: start]

You could dynamically allocate a `MyArray` variable like this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub DynamicDimension()

Dim NumRows As Long, NumCols As Long
Dim MyArray As Variant

'collect the number of rows from cell A1
'and the number of columns from cell B1
NumRows = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
NumCols = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value

'allocate array with dimensions collected from A1 and B1
ReDim MyArray(1 To NumRows, 1 To NumCols)

'output with message box to show that array is correctly dimensioned
MsgBox ("MyArray has " & UBound(MyArray, 1) & " rows.")
MsgBox ("MyArray has " & UBound(MyArray, 2) & " cols.")

End Sub
```

[image: end1]
[image: end2]

Comment: Awesome, @Dan: simple and tidy, just what I need. I'm still not sure where I was going wrong...

Comment: I think the issue stemmed from your variable type assignment. `r` and `c` were `Ranges`, and the dimensions of an `Array` must be numeric

Answer (score 4):

As requested, here is the `clsMatrix` class I had put together for my purposes; hopefully it can serve yours as well.

It includes:

- Matrix operations - `Add`, `Subtract`, `Multiply`, `ScalarMultiply`, `Augment`, `Transpose`
- Elementary Row Operations - `SwapRows`, `ScaleRow`, `AddScalarMultipleRow`
- A Parser for loading the Matrix from a String - `LoadMatrixString`
- Utility functions - `toString`, `Clone`
- An implementation of Gaussian Elimination - `RowReduce`

Here are a couple examples of usage:

```
Public Sub TestMatrix()

    Dim m1 As clsMatrix
    Set m1 = New clsMatrix
    m1.LoadMatrixString ("[[1,-3,1]," & _
                         " [1,1,-1]," & _
                         " [3,11,5]]")


    Dim m2 As clsMatrix
    Set m2 = New clsMatrix
    m2.LoadMatrixString ("[[9]," & _
                        " [1]," & _
                        " [35]]")

    MsgBox m1.Augment(m2).RowReduce.toString

End Sub

Public Sub TestMatrix2()
    'This is an example iteration of a matrix Petri Net as described here:
    'http://www.techfak.uni-bielefeld.de/~mchen/BioPNML/Intro/MRPN.html
    Dim D_Minus As clsMatrix
    Dim D_Plus As clsMatrix
    Dim D As clsMatrix

    Set D_Minus = New clsMatrix
    D_Minus.LoadMatrixString "[[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]," & _
                             " [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]," & _
                             " [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]," & _
                             " [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]"

    Set D_Plus = New clsMatrix
    D_Plus.LoadMatrixString "[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0]," & _
                            " [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]," & _
                            " [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]," & _
                            " [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]"


    Set D = D_Plus.Subtract(D_Minus)

    MsgBox D.toString

    Dim Transition_Matrix As clsMatrix
    Dim Marking_Matrix As clsMatrix
    Dim Next_Marking As clsMatrix

    Set Transition_Matrix = New clsMatrix
    Transition_Matrix.LoadMatrixString "[[0, 1, 1, 0]]"

    Set Marking_Matrix = New clsMatrix
    Marking_Matrix.LoadMatrixString "[[2, 1, 0, 0, 0]]"

    Set Next_Marking = Transition_Matrix.Multiply(D).Add(Marking_Matrix)

    MsgBox Next_Marking.toString

End Sub
```

And here is the `clsMatrix` class:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal Destination As Long, ByVal Source As Long, ByVal Length As Integer)
Private m_Arr() As Double

Private m_strMatrix As String
Private Look As String

Private Type SAFEARRAYBOUND
    cElements As Long
    lLbound As Long
End Type

Private Type SAFEARRAY
    cDims As Integer
    fFeatures As Integer
    cbElements As Long
    cLocks As Long
    pvData As Long
End Type

Private Type ARRAY_VARIANT
    vt As Integer
    wReserved1 As Integer
    wReserved2 As Integer
    wReserved3 As Integer
    lpSAFEARRAY As Long
    data(4) As Byte
End Type

Private Enum tagVARENUM
    VT_EMPTY = &H0
    VT_NULL
    VT_I2
    VT_I4
    VT_R4
    VT_R8
    VT_CY
    VT_DATE
    VT_BSTR
    VT_DISPATCH
    VT_ERROR
    VT_BOOL
    VT_VARIANT
    VT_UNKNOWN
    VT_DECIMAL
    VT_I1 = &H10
    VT_UI1
    VT_UI2
    VT_I8
    VT_UI8
    VT_INT
    VT_VOID
    VT_HRESULT
    VT_PTR
    VT_SAFEARRAY
    VT_CARRAY
    VT_USERDEFINED
    VT_LPSTR
    VT_LPWSTR
    VT_RECORD = &H24
    VT_INT_PTR
    VT_UINT_PTR
    VT_ARRAY = &H2000
    VT_BYREF = &H4000
End Enum

Public Sub Class_Initialize()

End Sub

'************************************************
'* Accessors and Utility Functions *
'***********************************

Public Property Get Value(r As Long, c As Long) As Double

    CheckDimensions

    Value = m_Arr(r, c)
End Property

Public Property Let Value(r As Long, c As Long, val As Double)

    CheckDimensions

    m_Arr(r, c) = val
End Property

Public Property Get Rows() As Long
    If GetDims(m_Arr) = 0 Then
        Rows = 0
    Else
        Rows = UBound(m_Arr, 1) + 1
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get Cols() As Long
    If GetDims(m_Arr) = 0 Then
        Cols = 0
    Else
        Cols = UBound(m_Arr, 2) + 1
    End If
End Property

Public Sub LoadMatrixString(str As String)
    m_strMatrix = str
    ParseMatrix str
    m_strMatrix = ""
    Look = ""
End Sub

Public Sub Resize(Rows As Long, Cols As Long, Optional blPreserve As Boolean = False)
    Dim tempMatrix As clsMatrix
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    If blPreserve Then

        CheckDimensions

        Set tempMatrix = Me.Clone
        ReDim m_Arr(0 To Rows - 1, 0 To Cols - 1)
        For r = 0 To MinLongs(tempMatrix.Rows, Me.Rows) - 1
            For c = 0 To MinLongs(tempMatrix.Cols, Me.Cols) - 1
                Value(r, c) = tempMatrix.Value(r, c)
            Next
        Next
    Else
        ReDim m_Arr(0 To Rows - 1, 0 To Cols - 1)
    End If

End Sub

Public Function Clone() As clsMatrix
    Dim mresult As clsMatrix
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    CheckDimensions

    Set mresult = New clsMatrix
    mresult.Resize Me.Rows, Me.Cols
    For r = 0 To Me.Rows - 1
        For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
            mresult.Value(r, c) = Me.Value(r, c)
        Next
    Next
    Set Clone = mresult
End Function

Public Function toString() As String
    Dim str As String
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim tempRow() As String
    Dim tempRows() As String
    ReDim tempRow(0 To Me.Cols - 1)
    ReDim tempRows(0 To Me.Rows - 1)


    If Not GetDims(m_Arr) = 0 Then 'Need to check if array is empty
        For r = 0 To Me.Rows - 1
            For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
                tempRow(c) = Me.Value(r, c)
            Next
            tempRows(r) = "[" & Join(tempRow, ", ") & "]"
        Next
        toString = "[" & Join(tempRows, vbCrLf) & "]"
    Else
        toString = ""
    End If
End Function

'***********************************************************
'* Matrix Operations *
'*********************

Public Function Add(m As clsMatrix) As clsMatrix
    Dim mresult As clsMatrix
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    CheckDimensions

    If m.Rows = Me.Rows And m.Cols = Me.Cols Then
        Set mresult = New clsMatrix
        mresult.Resize Me.Rows, Me.Cols
        For r = 0 To Me.Rows - 1
            For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
                mresult.Value(r, c) = Me.Value(r, c) + m.Value(r, c)
            Next
        Next
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "clsMatrix.Add", "Could not Add matrices: the Rows and Columns must be the same. The left matrix is (" & Me.Rows & ", " & Me.Cols & ") and the right matrix is (" & m.Rows & ", " & m.Cols & ")."
    End If
    Set Add = mresult
End Function

Public Function Subtract(m As clsMatrix) As clsMatrix
    Dim mresult As clsMatrix
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    CheckDimensions

    If m.Rows = Me.Rows And m.Cols = Me.Cols Then
        Set mresult = New clsMatrix
        mresult.Resize Me.Rows, Me.Cols
        For r = 0 To Me.Rows - 1
            For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
                mresult.Value(r, c) = Me.Value(r, c) - m.Value(r, c)
            Next
        Next
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 2, "clsMatrix.Subtract", "Could not Subtract matrices: the Rows and Columns must be the same. The left matrix is (" & Me.Rows & ", " & Me.Cols & ") and the right matrix is (" & m.Rows & ", " & m.Cols & ")."
    End If
    Set Subtract = mresult
End Function

Public Function Multiply(m As clsMatrix) As clsMatrix
    Dim mresult As clsMatrix
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim n As Long

    CheckDimensions

    If Me.Cols = m.Rows Then
        Set mresult = New clsMatrix
        mresult.Resize Me.Rows, m.Cols
        For i = 0 To Me.Rows - 1
            For j = 0 To m.Cols - 1
                For n = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
                    mresult.Value(i, j) = mresult.Value(i, j) + (Me.Value(i, n) * m.Value(n, j))
                Next
            Next
        Next
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 3, "clsMatrix.Multiply", "Could not Subtract matrices: the Columns of the left matrix and Rows of the right must be the same. The left matrix has " & Me.Cols & " Columns and the right matrix has " & m.Rows & " Rows."
    End If

    Set Multiply = mresult

End Function

Public Function ScalarMultiply(scalar As Double) As clsMatrix
    Dim mresult As clsMatrix
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    CheckDimensions

    Set mresult = New clsMatrix
    mresult.Resize Me.Rows, Me.Cols
    For r = 0 To Me.Rows - 1
        For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
            mresult.Value(r, c) = Me.Value(r, c) * scalar
        Next
    Next

    Set ScalarMultiply = mresult

End Function

Public Function Augment(m As clsMatrix) As clsMatrix
    Dim mresult As clsMatrix
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    CheckDimensions


    If Me.Rows = m.Rows Then
        Set mresult = New clsMatrix
        mresult.Resize Me.Rows, Me.Cols + m.Cols
        For r = 0 To Me.Rows - 1
            For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
                mresult.Value(r, c) = Me.Value(r, c)
            Next
        Next

        For r = 0 To Me.Rows - 1
            For c = 0 To m.Cols - 1
                mresult.Value(r, Me.Cols + c) = m.Value(r, c)
            Next
        Next
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 4, "clsMatrix.Augment", "Could not Augment matrices: the matrices must have the same number of Rows. The left matrix has " & Me.Rows & " Rows and the right matrix has " & m.Rows & " Rows."
    End If
    Set Augment = mresult
End Function

Public Function Transpose() As clsMatrix
    Dim mresult As clsMatrix
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long

    CheckDimensions

    If Me.Rows = Me.Cols Then
        Set mresult = New clsMatrix
        mresult.Resize Me.Cols, Me.Rows
        For r = 0 To Me.Rows - 1
            For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
                Me.Value(r, c) = mresult(c, r)
            Next
        Next
    Else
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 5, "clsMatrix.Augment", "Could not Transpose matrix: the matrix must have the same number of Rows and Cols. The matrix is (" & Me.Rows & ", " & Me.Cols & ")."
    End If
    Set Transpose = mresult
End Function

Public Function RowReduce() As clsMatrix
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    CheckDimensions

    'Row Echelon
    Dim mresult As clsMatrix
    Set mresult = Me.Clone

    For i = 0 To mresult.Rows - 1
        If Not mresult.Value(i, i) <> 0 Then
            For j = i + 1 To mresult.Rows - 1
                If mresult.Value(j, i) > 0 Then
                    mresult.SwapRows i, j
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If

        If mresult.Value(i, i) = 0 Then
            Exit For
        End If

        mresult.ScaleRow i, 1 / mresult.Value(i, i)

        For j = i + 1 To mresult.Rows - 1
            mresult.AddScalarMultipleRow i, j, -mresult.Value(j, i)
        Next
    Next

    'Backwards substitution

    For i = IIf(mresult.Rows < mresult.Cols, mresult.Rows, mresult.Cols) - 1 To 1 Step -1
        If mresult.Value(i, i) > 0 Then
            For j = i - 1 To 0 Step -1
                mresult.AddScalarMultipleRow i, j, -mresult.Value(j, i)
            Next
        End If
    Next

    Set RowReduce = mresult
End Function


'*************************************************************
'* Elementary Row Operaions *
'****************************

Public Sub SwapRows(r1 As Long, r2 As Long)
    Dim temp As Double
    Dim c As Long

    CheckDimensions

    For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
        temp = Me.Value(r1, c)
        Me.Value(r1, c) = Me.Value(r2, c)
        Me.Value(r2, c) = temp
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub ScaleRow(row As Long, scalar As Double)
    Dim c As Long

    CheckDimensions

    For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
        Me.Value(row, c) = Me.Value(row, c) * scalar
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub AddScalarMultipleRow(srcrow As Long, destrow As Long, scalar As Double)
    Dim c As Long

    CheckDimensions

    For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
        Me.Value(destrow, c) = Me.Value(destrow, c) + (Me.Value(srcrow, c) * scalar)
    Next
End Sub

'************************************************************
'* Parsing Functions *
'*********************

Private Sub ParseMatrix(strMatrix As String)
    Dim arr() As Double
    Dim c As Long
    GetChar 1
    Match "["
    SkipWhite
    If Look = "[" Then
        arr = ParseRow
        Me.Resize 1, UBound(arr) + 1
        'ReDim m_Arr(0 To UBound(arr), 0 To 0)
        For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
            Me.Value(0, c) = arr(c)
        Next
        SkipWhite
        While Look = ","
            Match ","
            SkipWhite
            arr = ParseRow
            Me.Resize Me.Rows + 1, Me.Cols, True

            If UBound(arr) <> (Me.Cols - 1) Then
                'Error jagged array
                Err.Raise vbObjectError + 6, "clsMatrix.LoadMatrixString", "Parser Error - Jagged arrays are not supported: Row 0 has " & Me.Cols & " Cols, but Row " & Me.Rows - 1 & " has " & UBound(arr) + 1 & " Cols."
            End If
            For c = 0 To Me.Cols - 1
                Me.Value(Me.Rows - 1, c) = arr(c)
            Next
            SkipWhite
        Wend
        Match "]"
    ElseIf Look = "]" Then
        Match "]"
    Else
        MsgBox "Error"
    End If
    SkipWhite
    If Look <> "" Then
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 7, "clsMatrix.LoadMatrixString", "Parser Error - Unexpected Character: """ & Look & """."
    End If
End Sub

Private Function ParseRow() As Variant
    Dim arr() As Double
    Match "["
    SkipWhite
    ReDim arr(0 To 0)
    arr(0) = ParseNumber
    SkipWhite
    While Look = ","
        Match ","
        ReDim Preserve arr(0 To UBound(arr) + 1)
        arr(UBound(arr)) = ParseNumber
        SkipWhite
    Wend
    Match "]"
    ParseRow = arr
End Function

Private Function ParseNumber() As Double
    Dim strToken As String
    If Look = "-" Then
        strToken = strToken & Look
        GetChar
    End If
    While IsDigit(Look)
        strToken = strToken & Look
        GetChar
    Wend
    If Look = "." Then
        strToken = strToken & Look
        GetChar
        While IsDigit(Look)
            strToken = strToken & Look
            GetChar
        Wend
    End If

    ParseNumber = CDbl(strToken)
End Function

'****************************************************************

Private Sub GetChar(Optional InitValue)
    Static i As Long
    If Not IsMissing(InitValue) Then
        i = InitValue
    End If
    If i <= Len(m_strMatrix) Then
        Look = Mid(m_strMatrix, i, 1)
        i = i + 1
    Else
        Look = ""
    End If
End Sub

'****************************************************************
'* Skip Functions *
'******************

Private Sub SkipWhite()
    While IsWhite(Look) Or IsEOL(Look)
        GetChar
    Wend
End Sub

'****************************************************************
'* Match/Expect Functions *
'**************************

Private Sub Match(char As String)
    If Look <> char Then
        Expected """" & char & """"
    Else
        GetChar
        SkipWhite
    End If
    Exit Sub

End Sub

Private Sub Expected(str As String)
    'MsgBox "Expected: " & str
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 8, "clsMatrix.LoadMatrixString", "Parser Error - Expected: " & str
End Sub

'****************************************************************
'* Character Class Functions *
'*****************************

Private Function IsDigit(char As String) As Boolean

    Dim charval As Integer
    If char <> "" Then
        charval = Asc(char)
        If 48 <= charval And charval <= 57 Then
            IsDigit = True
        Else
            IsDigit = False
        End If
    Else
        IsDigit = False
    End If

End Function

Private Function IsWhite(char As String) As Boolean

    Dim charval As Integer
    If char <> "" Then
        charval = Asc(char)
        If charval = 9 Or charval = 11 Or charval = 12 Or charval = 32 Or charval = 160 Then '160 because MS Exchange sucks
            IsWhite = True
        Else
            IsWhite = False
        End If
    Else
        IsWhite = False
    End If

End Function

Private Function IsEOL(char As String) As Boolean
    If char = Chr(13) Or char = Chr(10) Then
        IsEOL = True
    Else
        IsEOL = False
    End If
End Function

'*****************************************************************
'* Helper Functions *
'********************

Private Sub CheckDimensions()
    If GetDims(m_Arr) = 0 Then
        'Error, uninitialized array
        Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "clsMatrix", "Array has not been initialized"
    End If
End Sub

Private Function GetDims(VarSafeArray As Variant) As Integer
    Dim varArray As ARRAY_VARIANT
    Dim lpSAFEARRAY As Long
    Dim sArr As SAFEARRAY
    CopyMemory VarPtr(varArray.vt), VarPtr(VarSafeArray), 16&
    If varArray.vt And (tagVARENUM.VT_ARRAY Or tagVARENUM.VT_BYREF) Then
        CopyMemory VarPtr(lpSAFEARRAY), varArray.lpSAFEARRAY, 4&
        If Not lpSAFEARRAY = 0 Then
            CopyMemory VarPtr(sArr), lpSAFEARRAY, LenB(sArr)
            GetDims = sArr.cDims
        Else
            GetDims = 0  'The array is uninitialized
        End If
    Else
        GetDims = 0  'Not an array
    End If
End Function

Private Function MinLongs(a As Long, b As Long) As Long
    If a < b Then
        MinLongs = a
    Else
        MinLongs = b
    End If
End Function
```

If you should decide to try it and if you should encounter any problems/issues/unhandled exceptions, it would be very helpful to me if you could make note of them in a comment below.